# Kafka - How to Mock Consumer Record?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, mockito, junit5

I need some help with building a Junit test case for my Java kafka consumer.

My Original source code has the method as below, and need to create a Unit test case for the same.

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka-receiver-topic}")
public void receiveTopic(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord) throws Exception {
    JSONObject kafkaObject = new JSONObject(consumerRecord.value().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`ConsumerRecord` has a public constructor, so you can just create an instance yourself.

For example, modifying your code slightly:

Main:

```java
public JSONObject receiveTopic(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord) throws Exception {
    JSONObject kafkaObject = new JSONObject(consumerRecord.value().toString());
    return kafkaObject;
}
```

Test:

```java
@Test
public void testReceiveTopic() {
    ConsumerRecord<String, String> record = new ConsumerRecord<>("topic", 0, 123L, "key", "value");
    JSONObject expected = <what you expected>
    assertEquals(expected, receiveTopic(record));
}
```